# Load assembly error when using the powershell in command line

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have a load.PS1 and it loads 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo' as below

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::load('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo') | Out-Null
```

it works well when I use the ISE to load and run it , but get error when I run it in the powershell shell or use as "powershell -command ".\RemoveInvalidSSRSAgentJob.ps1 xxxx" as below

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly
 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find t
he file specified."
At line:1 char:38
+ & {[System.Reflection.Assembly]::load <<<< ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo') | Out-
Null}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

how can I set it so that it can work in the powershell shell or command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround using

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo')
```

but this method it's declared 'obsolete' from microsoft and in future can be eliminated.

The method load fails because it loads an assembly given the **long form of its name** but your ar passing to it a partial name: [Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx). 
And I find really strange that in ISE works, for me fails!

Comment: thanks, it helps. 
but could you explain why the "Load" does not work?
I would like to know the root cause.